# Remove specific images from browser cache

Tags: javascript, caching

My application kind of looks like a carousal where in the user marks the image accordingly by clicking on the relevant button and then the next image is loaded.

To make this application work faster, I am caching 10 images at a time. When the user is at 8th image, I cache another 10 images ahead of time (11th to 20th). When it is at 18, I cache the next 10 (21st to 30th), and so on. For caching, I do the following in a `for` loop:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://some-site/some-image.jpg'; // different image URL each time, of course
```

Now, the problem is the app gets slower when there are like 500 images in the cache. I tested it for 700+ images and the app gets really *really* slow.

Is there a way to remove the image from the browser cache once the user has marked it?

---

**Update 1:**  Relevant part of my code:

```
    for (var i = start, l=start+10; i < l; i++) {

        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {
            console.log('images loaded in cache');
            var index = list.indexOf(this);
            if (index !== -1) {
                // remove image from the array once it's loaded
                // for memory consumption reasons
                list.splice(index, 1);
            }
        };

        list.push(img);

        img.src = 'https://xxx/xxx/' + screenshotFilenames[i];

    }
```

Comment: have you tried storing the `img` variable in an array during your looping and performing `delete` to the ones you want to remove?

Comment: @WillP. - That will almost work :)

Comment: @WillP. In my code, I am already removing the image from the array once it is loaded. Let me put up the relevant part of the code in my question above.

Comment: @WillP. There you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

First and foremost, the browser cache on disk cannot be altered by JavaScript. The cache on disk will grow as the amount of images that have been loaded grows and there is no stopping that.

What you can control is the amount of memory the browser is allocating in the page. This comes down to how many references exist to your images. I am not sure if you are using the same design scheme as shown in your post, but basically you have shown an image in the global scope.

This needs to change. The lifetime of the variable holding the images needs to exist for a smaller amount of time. That way it can lose scope. Once it has lost scope it will be a candidate for garbage collection. However, if its scope remains, it will not be collected.

Garbage collection will iterate the set of execution contexts stored on the page recursively and examine whether or not their variable environments contain eligible candidates. Note that everything in the global scope is in the lexical environment, and as a result will never be garbage collected until the page unloads.

So you need to move the temporary array of cached or "active" images into a variable environment somewhere, and ensure that it loses scope once the elements are placed on the page or in a queue which also loses scope.

Comment: I am removing the array already. Please refer to the update in my question.

Comment: A for loop does not create an execution context. For example: `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    var img = "test";
}
alert(img);` will show "test" because of variable hoisting outside of the loop to the top of the current execution context.

Comment: Gotcha! Will solve it if I use IIFE? `(function(){ /*for loop here*/ })();`

Comment: That *may* help, it will definitely prevent the `img` variable from being leaked too far. It is hard to tell without a little more containing code to show the scope.

Comment: Ok, I have added IIFE now. But as you see in my code, I am already deleting the image from the array. I do not see a way to remove it from the cache though, using Javascript. Looks like the cache cant be altered by Javascript.